# Reduce Active Directory users in Jira using LDAP Query

Tags: ldap, jira, jira-rest-api, ldap-query, jira-agile

I am retrieving users for Active directory in Jira 7 by using LDAP. I am trying to reduce the number of users brought from LDAP to a particular group that we have created. So in order to do that i put (objectCategory=group)(cn=WebAgileDevs) in the group object filter along with the default settings. The only thing i change is the Base DN and credentials required. When i save and test it does show me that it is testing 1 group and 15 users which is what i want!(See the screenshot). BUT, when i go and sync it, it brings in 43000 users!! What am i missing???

[Test Remote Directory Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNQcI.png)

Answer (score 1):

The group filter is used to filter the list of *groups* that are imported to JIRA, and the user filter is used to filter the list of *users* that are imported to JIRA. The two need not necessarily correspond. Your group filter would be instructing JIRA to bring in only that one group (into the list of groups), but without further refinement, your user filter will still be pulling in all users, as you noticed. This means that you need to adjust the user filter too.

From your question, you want to import only those users who are a member of a specific group. Atlassian provides some general guidance [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-write-ldap-search-filters-792496933.html).

The last example on that page is particularly relevant for you:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf=cn=CaptainPlanet,ou=users,dc=company,dc=com))
```

This tells JIRA to pull in only those user objects that are a member of the group `cn=CaptainPlanet,ou=users,dc=company,dc=com`. You would want to replace this with your `cn=WebAgileDevs` (plus whatever trailing qualifiers you need to fully qualify the group name).